# Write-byte instruction on Raspberry Pi node

Tags: javascript, node.js, bit-manipulation, byte, gpio

I've received for Christmas a rasberry pi with the blinkt led kit. I've started to play with it in python, but I wanted to play with it with my favourite language. So I looked at the npm port of the python library. Overall I get the flow, but then I've seen this kind of operation.

```
function writeByte(byte) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    dat.writeSync(byte & 0x80 ? 1 : 0);
     clk.writeSync(1);
     byte <<= 1;
     clk.writeSync(0);
    }
  }
```

That I completely don't understand. I get that there is some byte(?) Action there, but how you work out what concatenate to the string e.g: the 0x80? I'm trying to find out how to improve this knowledge to play a bit with this GPIO pins. I apologize if I've mixed up terms, but I'm lost and in will to learn to deal with this kind of operations.

https://github.com/NotNinja/node-blinkt/blob/master/src/blinkt.js this is the library src code

Comment: `the string e.g: the 0x80` ... for a start `0x80` is not a string

Comment: What it is then?

Comment: it's a hexadecimal number 0x80(hex) === 128(dec) === 10000000(binary)

Comment: What could be then a good starting place for learning this kind of knowledge? Because I'm familiar in programming but not at this low level..

Comment: I've never heard javascript described as a low level language

Comment: I never defined it as a low level language, but those kind of instruction are low level and I want to know where to look to understand what's going on.